# Center of mass of points in log scale chart

Tags: mathematical-physics

I would like to know what is the way to find the center of mass of some scattered points in a 2D plane where scales are logarithmic?

Is it safe to first convert them to normal scale and then compute X_mean and Y_mean and then convert that to log scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you don't "convert" the coordinates to normal scale, you just read the values using the tick marks, and they are already what you need.

$$\frac{1+2+100}3,\frac{1+10+100}3.$$

[image]

Comment: The red point shouldn't be somewhere in the middle of the triangle?

Comment: @mahmood: Try by yourself.